# Is it safe to transfer C++ objects among shared libs with the extern "C"?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

Suppose I have C++ object, like std::function. Is it safe in every way to pass such an object to another dynamically loaded shared library like this:

```cxx
// lib
extern "C"
{
void call( void* f )
{
    auto f_callable = (std::function<void()>*)f;
    f_callable->operator()();
}
}
```

```cxx
// executable
auto call = ( void (*) ( void* ) ) dlsym( lib_, "call" );
std::function<void()> f = []{
    printf( "called" );
};
call( ( void* )&f );
```

What if the library and executable are compiled by different compilers (like clang and GCC)? Or by different versions of the same compiler?

Comment: In general, no.   Since the definition of the function casts to a C++ type, the library and the program using it would need to be built with the same (or compatible) C++ compiler.   C++ compilers from different vendors are generally not compatible in the way needed (e.g. same ABI, same layout of C++ struct/class types).   Even different versions of one compiler may be incompatible (e.g. the targeted ABI has been known to change between major versions of some compilers - although it doesn't happen often, it does happen).

Comment: I follow a few strict rule here myself, do not leak C++ types over interfaces and dont cast to and from void*. There is no guarantee those types will be compatible over compilers or even between versions of compilers. (or STL implementations)

Comment: @Peter I don't think the ABI and layout of struct/class types will be a problem. Changes in the calling convention aren't that common. Possible sure, but unlikely. The problem I see as most likely is the compilers using different STLs. `std::function` in one compiler might not be the same as `std::function` in the other because their STLs implement it differently.

Comment: I'm a bit mystified why you want to do this at all.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow     I disagree.  The reason that two different STLs *can* implement a  (templated) class type like `std::function` differently is that the standard specifies that layout of all class types (other than particular categories such as POD) is implementation-defined (and data members, if any, of `std::function` are unspecified).    Among other things, that means passing a class type from (code built with) one compiler to another means the receiving code *assumes* a different layout in memory of the object it receives.

Comment: @Peter The layout is part of the calling convention (i.e. the collection of ABI, alignment, padding, register/stack usage for arguments and return types, ...). If you tell gcc to compile for windows PE then it will follow the same calling convention as msvc and you can link object files together just fine. But if they use a different implementation of std::function, as in the source for them differs, then no amount of ABI and layout compatibility will help you.

Comment: @PaulSanders I want to build a modular system, so that users could write and install their own extensions without recompiling the whole application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is defined behavior, provided that both parts of the C++ code gets generated by the same exact compiler. Casting the same thing to/from a `void *` is defined behavior. Presuming that the second C++ code sees the same C linkage, this is also defined behavior.

Whether or not it is safe when different compilers or different versions of the compilers are involved depends on whatever ABI guarantees these compilers provide. You will need to check their respective documentation to determine that.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that according to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html) all GCC versions starting from 3.2 are compatible in a needed way (excluding "_Some GCC compilation options_")?

Comment: No, pay attention to this part: "there is no formal ABI for the Standard C++ Library.". You may compile your own code, and just your own code, and have the binary ABI be upwards compatible. As soon as any part of the standard C++ library gets linked with, all warranties are void. No `std::cout`. No `std::string`, No `std::vector`, etc...

Comment: It's maybe off topic but I'm curious whether it's possible to get around this limitation by using inheritance and virtual functions. Suppose that same `std::function` and suppose I've made my own interface, and some proxy object implementing this interface: [link](https://pastebin.com/S9RHBkw6).
Then, according to ABI compatibility of different GCC versions (which I _suppose_ should include vtables compatibility) it should safe to use it like this:
```void call( void* f )
{
    auto f_callable = (MyFunctionInterface*)f;
    f_callable->operator()();
}
```
Am I right?

Comment: Do you think that virtual function dispatch implementation is something that's implemented exactly the same across all compilers and all versions of every compiler, thusly guaranteeing this kind of assured compatibility? How well acquainted are you with common virtual dispatch techniques, like carrying a hidden pointer in every object, to a compiler-generated virtual dispatch table with pointers to that particular object's virtual functions, as well as the necessary offsets for mapping `this` for the virtual function call? C++ is complicated.